# Spring-Data-Neo4j: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, exception, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to configure `Spring-Data-Neo4j` example with java based configuration. When i trying to run test case, the following stack trace print. According to the exception is that, For transaction Neo4jTemplate get multiple transaction manager as i thought.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: neo4jTransactionManager,jtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:354)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:256)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.findBySchemaPropertyValue(Unknown Source)
at com.harmeetsingh13.repositorytest.NodePersistenceTest.getObjectFromRepo(NodePersistenceTest.java:49)
```

My Neo4j Java based configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value="classpath:properties/db.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.harmeetsingh13.entities")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.harmeetsingh13.repository")
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jAspectConfiguration{

@Resource
private Environment env; 

public Neo4jConfig() {
    setBasePackage("com.harmeetsingh13.entities");
}

@Bean(name = "graphDatabaseService")
public GraphDatabaseService getGraphDatabaseService(){
    GraphDatabaseFactory databaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    return databaseService.newEmbeddedDatabase(env.getProperty("db.store.directory"));
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "jtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean")
public JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean neo4jTransactionManagerFactoryBean
    (GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) throws Exception {
    JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = 
            new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(graphDatabaseService);
    return factoryBean;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name= {"neo4jTransactionManager"})
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager
    (JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean jtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager = new ChainedTransactionManager(jtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
}
```

My Test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional(value = "neo4jTransactionManager")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Neo4jConfig.class, loader =  AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class NodePersistenceTest {

@Autowired
private Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;
@Autowired
private RepositoryMovie movieRepo;

@Test
@Transactional
public void persistMovie() {
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setId(13L);
    movie.setTitle("Dark Knight");
    Movie returnMovie = neo4jTemplate.save(movie);

    assertThat(returnMovie, notNullValue());
}

@Test
public void getObjectFromRepo() {
    Movie movie = movieRepo.findBySchemaPropertyValue("id", 13);

    assertThat(movie, notNullValue());
}
}
```

In the test case, the first test case will run successfully, but the exception produce on second test case and our test case is fail.